# Get data from one array by ID from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

More or less the situation is like this: I get an array (using JS) and one object (let's call it TASK) looks like this (it's not the full array, just ONE instance):

```
{
      "id": "28",
      "name": "sdfsdf",
      "progress": 80,
      "description": "",
      "code": "1",
      "level": 1,
      "status": "STATUS_SUSPENDED",
      "depends": "",
      "canWrite": true,
      "start": 1444341600000,
      "duration": 7,
      "end": 1445291999999,
      "startIsMilestone": 0,
      "endIsMilestone": 0,
      "collapsed": false,
      "assigs": [
        {
          "resourceId": 3,
          "otherStuff": xyz
        },
        {
          "resourceId": 2,
          "otherStuff": xyz
        }
      ],
      "hasChild": true
    }
```

The other object that I load contains all "resources", referred in the first array with "assigs": [] (let's call these RESOURCES):

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "name": "service | 1st resource we need",
    "unit": "pcs",
    "quantity": "10"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "name": "money | Office space",
    "unit": "hour",
    "quantity": "50"
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "name": "product | Money for nothing...",
    "unit": "$",
    "quantity": "300"
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "name": "people | Chovjek",
    "unit": "people",
    "quantity": "1"
  }
]
```

I populate some form fields with task data, but there is simply no way I can figure out how to "connect" the task with its resources.

Comment: How your output should look like ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand but looks like you need to get `task.assigs.resourceId` inside an each loop and then use the value to find the `resources.id` like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181493/how-to-find-a-value-in-a-multidimensional-object-array-in-javascript

Comment: Are you looking for something like a function which can update your resources array on the basis of your action in form to assign them to a task?

Comment: The output of the whole task looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/4e5ubLY.png) I marked the resources with red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this if we are talking newer versions of javascript:

```
for(var task of tasks)
{
    for(var ass of task.assigns)
    {
        for(var res of resources)
        {
            if(res.ID === ass.resourceId.toString()) {
                //here res and ass match and you can do what you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In all versions of JS you can do it like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++)
{
    for(var x = 0; x< tasks[i].assigns.length; x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < resources.length; y++)
        {
            if(resources[y].ID === tasks[i].assigns[x].resourceId.toString()) {
                //here res and ass match and you can do what you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just added the calls to toString - because in your sample one is a string and the other is a number.

Comment: Sir you won today :) This works! (used the first one, only instead of vars i used lets ;) ). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best answer there is, but I'd probably use the the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

You loop through all your tasks (in a foreach loop for instance), and then you loop through each assig(?), and then do:

```
for (var task of tasks) {
    for (var currentAssig of assigs) {
        var resourceId = currentAssig.resourceId;
        var relevantResource = RESOURCES.filter(function (res) {
            return res.ID === resourceId;
        });
        // do whatever you want with your resource.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of "resourceId" you just set your Resource object in there?
You will have your connection:

```
{
  "id": "28",
  "name": "sdfsdf",
  /* .... */
  "assigs": [
    {
      "resource":
       {
            "ID": "1",
            "name": "service | 1st resource we need",
            "unit": "pcs",
            "quantity": "10"
       },
      "otherStuff": xyz
    },
    {
      "resource":
       {
            "ID": "2",
            "name": "service | 2nd resource we need",
            "unit": "pcs",
            "quantity": "20"
       },
      "otherStuff": xyz
    }
  ],
  "hasChild": true
}
```

Or, if you want to keep your structure, just add a reference to object that exists in the Resources array:

```
"assigs":
[
    {
      "resourceId": 3,
      "resource": yourResourceArray[0], //<-- [0] for sake of simplicity
      "otherStuff": xyz
    },
    {
      "resourceId": 2,
      "resource": yourResourceArray[1], //<-- [1] for sake of simplicity
      "otherStuff": xyz
    }
],
```

Comment: This is a client side code, although you can make your backend write it on your page. But the point is, you can connect/link your array items to other array items. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether or not this is what you're looking for, but you should be able to loop through the `Task` array, and inside that loop, loop through the `assigs` array, and inside this loop, loop through your `Resources` array. Doing this, you can find the connection.

**Example:**

```
//Loop through Task array
for(i = 0; i < Task.length; i++){
    //Loop through your assigs within the Task array, at the given index 'i'
    for(j =0; j < Task[i].assigs; j++){
        //Now loop through the Resources array, to find the ID that matches the assigs 'resourceId'
        for(k =0; k < Resources.length; k++){
            if(Task[i].assigs[j].resourceId === Resources[k].ID){
                //You have the connection
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** this could probably be optimized fairly much, but at least here's the principal

***EDIT:*** or as Christian Nielsen does, using a foreach loop

Comment: Gonna try this approach right away, I'll let you know the outcome ;)