# Check if value is in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a multidimensional array, where I'd like to check if a value is in it. I've tried `Array.includes("value")`, but nothing came up. This is my code:

```
var database = [{
 "identifier": "test1",
 "extra": "information1"
},{
 "identifier": "test2",
 "extra": "information2"
},{
 "identifier": "test3",
 "extra": "information3"
}
]
```

How do I test if `"identifier"` is in my array?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `some` method `database.some(({identifier}) => identifier == "test1")`

Comment: already answered check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181493/how-to-find-a-value-in-a-multidimensional-object-array-in-javascript/15299578

Comment: database.length > 0 && database[0].hasOwnProperty("identifier")

Answer (score -1):

hi see below code which read each element of your database and print "identifier" value of each element.

```js
var database = [{
 "identifier": "test1",
 "extra": "information1"
},{
 "identifier": "test2",
 "extra": "information2"
},{
 "identifier": "test3",
 "extra": "information3"
}
]

$.each(database, function(index, value) {

if(value.identifier.length>0)
  console.log(value.identifier);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Question is not tagged jQuery